# In visual studio 2012 cannot return to code from exception

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2012

There is very useful feature in all previous versions of Visual Studio: if I make a break point in catch block of try...catch construction then when an exception occurs I can drag the current position of code to try block. It allows me to see what error occurred. For example:

```
try
{
    int i=0;
    int j=1/i;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    string s="";  //here I may set a break point and then drag a cursor to try block
}
```

But it is not possible in VS 2012! I can't return to try block. May be I missed something in options? It's very sad if they cancelled this feature.
**Solution**:
My web site was under application pool ASP.NET V4.0 Integrated where property "Enable 32-bit applications" was set to false. When I changed application pool to other one and set this property to True I succeeded to return to try block

Comment: Your sure your compiler isn't just removing lines of code that dont do anything?

Comment: Just tried it, without problems. Works like a charme.

Comment: Why don't you look at the StackTrace to see where the Exception came from?

Comment: The `Exception` object has all kinds of information about what caused it. I don't understand how returning to the try block, which will utlimately just throw the exeption again, is useful.

Comment: For example an exception occurred in a cycle by i for some value of i. How can I see in catch block the value of i?

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that in Visual Studio 2010 either, this is nothing new in Visual Studio 2012.

**Edit: Unless it's Ultimate it seems (with Intellitrace enabled)**.

Comment: I never knew you could do that in versions previous to 2010, interesting.

Comment: @Kai Never worked for me, are you sure it isn't a setting or something?

Comment: @Bob. I don't recall ever being able to do it. I know for certain you can't in 2010 because lord knows I've tried :)

Comment: @mattytommo I installed VS yesteday (Got windows 8 ultrabook! Yeah!) and changed nothing or installed an addin.

Comment: @Kai Nice! Maybe it's a Win 8 thing?

Comment: What version of VS are you all using?  Express, Pro, Ultimate?

Comment: @mattytommo At the moment I don't have access to a windows 7 machine, but it would be a huge suprise if this is a windows 8 thing.

Comment: @Kai I've got a couple of editions of VS, let me check them all.

Comment: If you have `IntelliTrace` enabled, it shows you the exception too. Even the thread, and related views (locals, call stack, exception settings)

Comment: It exist in Ultimate only. I have Premium.

Answer (score 2):

Looks that the functionality you're asking for is only build in if you're using the ultimate version of visual studio:

[Step through a program backwards after an Exception has occurred - Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408786/step-through-a-program-backwards-after-an-exception-has-occurred-visual-studio)

I use ultimate and IntelliTrace makes it possible:

[image]

[image]