# StepBack debug option in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Im trying to find out how I can manage to do a stepback in debugging.

How this function works is described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/10/21/the-future-of-debugging-is-here-visual-studio-2010-now-supports-stepping-back-in-the-debugger/).

Another usage Im looking for is when debugging, system stops on exception being thrown. I like to be able to jump backwards to the function that called current function and so on. How can I achieve this functionality in VS2015 Community?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/

Comment: A workaround I could think of is that we could use the Call Stack.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408786/step-through-a-program-backwards-after-an-exception-has-occurred-visual-studio

Comment: @user2279379, how about using the Call Stack for this issue?